# WPF Application not scrolling with touch on some Windows 10 tablets

Tags: wpf, windows, touch

I have a WPF application that includes a screen that users can scroll up and down. It has a scroll viewer control which provides a scroll bar and you can also scroll up and down using touch to drag the content up or down. This all works fine on all of my PCs, laptops and tablets and on most of my clients laptops and tablets.

However, I have one client who can only scroll the form up and down using the scroll bar. Using touch to drag and drop the contents of the form does not work.

I have seen this before on another tablet and we found that by installing all of the Windows updates the problem was resolved. However, on this tablet Windows is saying there are no more updates and the problem still exists.

The tablet is a Linx 10 that had Windows 10 on it from the start - it's not an upgrade. My hunch is that it needs the relevant Windows update but that Windows isn't reporting it as a required update.

Has anyone experienced this and identified what files/updates are needed to resolve it?

Just to re-iterate the application works fine on most PCs and tablets, so I don't think it's a basic coding problem which is why I haven't included any code.

Comment: After a lot of debugging and pulling things apart I discovered the problem was down to a third party control on the page that grabbed all the touch input and thereby prevented other areas from receiving touch input. This problem only occurred on Windows 10 so there must be something slightly different with Windows 10.

Comment: May I ask what kind of third party control it was? We have a similar problem...